# Access folder form client device using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I had complete server/ client desktop software using c# and sql server for E-library,so I had designed the server software to save a pdf file in folder and save the path of this file in database is thier any way to open this file from client device using path stored in sql server database???

Comment: "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" ?

Comment: yes for microsoft netwroks

Comment: I think that the folder should be a Windows Share folder or disk. So it can be visible as a network drive in your infrastructure network. After that, you can navigate to it using your server software, stated that is visible from the machine executing server software